# Does spring boot have any out-of-box support for multi-tenancy for jdbctemplate like they do for JPA(AbstractRoutingDataSource)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We do not have a persistence layer, we are just using jdbcTemplate to make the calls. Every things that requires transactional works is done in the procedure side of things. I still want to implement multi-tenancy though similar to the jpa route (abstractroutingdatasource). Is there a out-of-box way to do this in spring boot?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21876

Comment: And why wouldn't `AbstractROutingDataSource` work for JDBC? It has nothing to do with JPA.